# how to instantiate a functional component in vue 2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I have a functional component in my project, now I need to instantiate it to handle it in JS.

What should I do?

---

I've tried `Vue.extend()`, it does not work.

I've found someone's code like this:

```js
function createInstance(FunctionalComponent, vnodeData) {
  const instance = new Vue({
    el: document.createElement('div'),
    props: FunctionalComponent.props,
    render(h) {
      return h(
        FunctionalComponent,
        {
          props: this.$props, // why use `this.$props` here?
          ...vnodeData,
        }
      )
    }
  })

  return instance
}
```

This works for me, but I wonder why he uses `this.$props` in the `h` function's param?

It seems like it doesn't work if use `FunctionalComponent.props` instead, why?